# Can you earn a shorter posting interval?

Tags: support

I tried to post two questions, on different topics, and got an error message saying `You can only post once every 40 minutes.` I assumed that this was because of my low reputation score, but I checked the privilege list and didn't see anything about being able to post more often. So:

**Can one earn the right to post more frequently, and, if so, how?**

Comment: Refer to https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/a/353. What I'm interested in knowing is: let's say I'm a 16k user on Android.se and 17k user on superuser. If I post a question on Superuser, can I post a question on Android.se within 40 minutes or would I have to wait? I'm sure, if I try on say bitcoin.se (with only association bonus) than I'd have to wait for 40 minutes.

Comment: What defines a new user? I've been on SE sites for several years now. Moreover, I've never run into this issue on any other SE domain; only this one.

Comment: "New user" means "has less than 125 reputation on the site where a question was posted". Meta.SE has [a guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164900/150283) that outlines the current rate-limiting rules.

Answer (score 3):

Per [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164899/21960):

> Users with < 125 rep, [40 minutes since their last question anywhere on the network](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/322265) (This applies to the user's IP address, not their account. If the user shares that IP with other users, they can be limited by the other user asking a question anywhere on the network.)